# How to setup C# downcasting in a more dynamic way

Tags: c#, oop, downcast

Apologies if the title is not quite right.
I've got a set of base classes I am deriving from. There is a main one and a bunch of components I can add onto it.

```cs
    public class Entity {
        public EntityPart ep;
    }
    public class EntityPart {
        public void eFunc() {}
    }
```

My derived classes work perfect for all my virtual functions obviously. But here's the problem I ran into

```cs
    public class dEntity : Entity {
        public void someFunc() {
            ep.derivedFunc(); // Error, does not exist on EntityPart
        }
    }
    public class dEntityPart : EntityPart {
        public void derivedFunc() {}
    }
```

I pretty quickly figured out what was going on. Since `ep` was still just an `EntityPart` it didn't have the derived functionality.

I found a solution that worked but felt like something was off. When I asked others they seemed confused that my code didn't work before.

```cs
    public class dEntity : Entity {
        public new dEntityPart ep {
            get { return (dEntityPart)base.ep; }
        }
    }
```

As I understand this is simply declaring a variable named `ep` as the type `dEntityPart`. This is a property and has the get function that casts `base.ep` (which is just `EntityPart`) as a `dEntityPart`. The `new` keyword hides base from within the class.
I'd like to double check first that this understanding is correct.

This worked just as I needed but it seemed messy. I have many sets of derivations of these class, each with many parts. This method feels a little slow and cumbersome. Is there a way to set up this down casting to always be there, or perhaps a way to setup some generic to work like this?

If this is the way to do it, alrighty. I'm interested in perhaps a more elegant method or some better way to set up such code. Thanks!

Comment: looks like you are looking for [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
    public class Entity<T> where T : EntityPart {
        public T ep;
    }
    public class EntityPart {
        public void eFunc() {}
    }
```

```
    public class dEntity : Entity<dEntityPart> {
        public void someFunc() {
            ep.derivedFunc(); // This won't throw an error anymore.
        }
    }
    public class dEntityPart : EntityPart {
        public void derivedFunc() {}
    }
```

Comment: That looks to be it! Unsure why I couldn't seem to find the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Mind if I stick a little follow up here? I might have many derivations of `EntityParts` and a single entity might have up  to 5 or 6 different parts on it. That seems like the declaration would become a mouthful. Do you think that would be an issue, or is there a way around such a thing?

Comment: That would indeed be a problem anyway you choose to proceed. You will either need a `Entity<T1,T2,...>` declarataion (I have only seen Func<> having so many declarations), or a lot of boilerplate code. If everything is a part, can't you just find the common functionality and use it as inhecritance intended?

Comment: I will have to put it into my work and see who it goes. While they are all parts they each take care of some different functionality. I'm trying to create a rather modular design. I will get back to you.

Comment: What you have will work but sadly with Unity, what I'm using, I can't do this so straightforwardly.  Just in case, is there another method to downcast besides what I had?